# Get full time zone name given an instance of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

Given an `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` time instance, how can I return a full time zone name for the time instance?

From the ActiveSupport docs:

```
Time.zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'   # => "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
time = Time.zone.now
time.zone # => "EST"
```

So, given a time object, I can easily get the *time zone abbreviation* using `time.zone`, but how can i get a full time zone name? In the example from the docs this would be `"Eastern Time (US & Canada)"` (I'd also be happy with `"America/New_York"`)?

I realize that time zone name's aren't standardized, and at this point I'd be happy to find a way to convert the abbreviation to any non-abbreviated format (e.g. `"Eastern Time (US & Canada)"` or `"America/New_York"`).

There doesn't appear to be any built in reverse mapping of time zone abbreviations back to time zones. At least, I haven't found it. Obviously I could create my own mapping, but it seems *quite likely* this is a solved problem.

Comment: [`time.zone.name`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html)?

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks, but the return of `time.zone` is a standard string, so no `name()` method.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be that I am not interacting with an instance of `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` like I thought.

`ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` should have a `time_zone` attribute which returns what I want, but the standard `Time` object just has a `zone()` method which returns a string time zone abbreviation.

Comment: This is weirdly difficult to find. that the time_zone itself is a central attribute should be super obvious, but the documentation for TimeWithZone glosses over it in a way that made me go searching for how I've accessed this in the past

Answer (score 1):

It looks like abbreviations are not unique. So one single abbr like "ACT" can mean 2 different time zones, one in south america and one on Australia https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/. That would explain why ruby doesn't have a built in way to do what you need.

Maybe you can use this gem https://github.com/davispuh/TimezoneParser